# Which word correctly follows "my fascination"?

Tags: prepositions

If I want to express how I find a field of study fascinating, should I say:

> ...my fascination ***with*** this field...

OR

> ...my fascination ***of*** this field...

OR

> ...my fascination ***for*** this field...

OR a completely different word?

Comment: It's not a particularly common usage (we're more likely to speak of our ***passion*** or ***enthusiasm for*** [something]), but in general it's ***The** fascination **of** [something which is fascinating in and of itself]* when assigning the fascinating qualities to the thing, and ***My** fascination **with** [the thing]* when assigning the state of being fascinated to the person rather than the thing.

Comment: "fascination with", "fascination for", "fascination of", "fascination in" can all be used depending on the context.

Longman (https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/fascination) example sentences.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, the preposition to be used depends on the intended meaning of the word 'fascination'. If something fascinates me I can say that it holds a fascination for me. On the other hand, if I have a great interest in something, I may well be fascinated with it. In the latter case I could also say 'I am fascinated by...'

A similar turn of phrase also comes to mind: 'I have a liking for...' Note, however, that 'fascination of' would be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options here:

1. You can say "**This field is a fascination for me**", here it means that "**this field has power to fascinate you**".
2. You can say "**I am fascinated with this field**", here it means that "**you are in the state of being fascinated**"
3. You can say "**I am fascinated by the field**", here it means that "**you are fascinated by it**"
4. You can say "**This field is a fascination to me**", here it means that "**You are interested in this field very much**"

[Lingvo help - Prepositions after "**fascinating**"](https://lingohelp.me/preposition-after-adjective/fascinating-to-about-in-for-as/)